# Синонимизировать [редактирование] и [правки]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, мета

У нас на мете есть идентичные метки: [редактирование](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [правки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8). Я бы основной сделал болеё ёмкую, на мой взгляд, метку [правки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8), даже несмотря на отсутствие описания и меньшее количестово вопросов. Также эта метка более гармонично будет смотреться с [отклонённые-правки](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8) и [предлагаемые-правки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Comment: Вполне разумно...

Comment: Я бы сказал, что самая важная причина, говорящая в пользу этого –  это русский язык! В русском языке нет такого слова как «редактирование». + слова «Синонимизировать» также в русском не существует, зато есть «Отождествлять» и «Отождествить».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метки объединены и синонимизированы

Comment: А можете каким-то образом перенести на [meta-tag:правки] описание метки с "редактирования" или оно, получается, что утеряно безвозвратно?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, спросил у знающих. Когда ответят - тут напишу)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, речь [об этом описании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/635/revisions)? А то они все анонимные после удаления...

Comment: @Qwertiy Вроде да. Но я не знаю, насколько оно подходит к метке [meta-tag:правки]. Хотя уверен лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а вот краткое: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/636/revisions

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, немного их переписал и приделал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо большое! Синонимизация, которая не убивает описания намного лучше:)